# Run java code on client machine

Tags: java, jsp, applet, jsp-tags

I want to run a java code which uses JNA to find out whether the client machine is idle or not. This code must run on the client side JVM instead of server's JVM hence I can't put the code inside servlets. I was able to achieve this by using applets. But as I dont want any GUI and want this code to run in background, is there any way to run a piece of code on cilent's JVM?
 I am using `<jsp:plugin type="applet">` . What does `type = "bean"` is used for? Which using bean solve the purpose?

Comment: Why exactly would a server care if a client machine was 'idle'?  I can think of a few possible reasons, most of them things that should not be done.

Comment: I know that should not be done. But here the requirement is like that. The web application that will be running on the client machine should lock the screen once the system is idle for a particular period of time. The client machine is a dedicated machine for this particular server so permissions and securities are not of any great concern.

Comment: Have a service running on the client machine that does the idle check/locking.

Comment: Thats not possible. I ll try to explain the requirement in short. My webpage will open a  thrid party web page in a popup window. If the user is idle on that 3rd aprty web page  that popup window must be closed. Now, the problem is once the user redirects to the 3rd party page, I don't have any control on that page, so javascripts or servlets won't help. That's y I am detecting if the system is idle so that I can close the window. If I am running a service, I won't have a reference for the popup window. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: ..it really seems like this app. is an unworkable mess.

Comment: Why not run a proxy from the server to present the content from the 3rd party pop-up?  And for user's sake, don't make it a pop-up!

Comment: Ok, even If I don't make it a pop up how am I gonna check whether the user is idle on the 3rd party's web page and redirect him/her to my page.

Comment: If it is coming through a proxy, it becomes if not 'your page', then at least content that you control.  Take it by the bits and do as you will with it!

Comment: I am not sure how to do that as I am a beginner. Can you provide me with an example or some links where I can study the entire proxy thing. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is an invisible applet, why not just absolute-position it offscreen?

Comment: That would be a work around, which I have thought about. But, I want an alternative for applets.